# How to allow to read only first 3 files from a directory in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Below is the code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const log = console.log;
const path = require( "path" );
const folderPath = 'Data';
const folder = folderPath;
let counter = 0;

 fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach(file => {
    const extname = path.extname(file);
    const filename = path.basename(file, extname);
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(folder, file);

    const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
        mergeAttrs: true,
        explicitArray: false
    });
    
counter++;

fs.readFile(absolutePath, (err, data) => {

        parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                 if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("mydb");
                 dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(result, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
console.log("XML Uploaded Succesfully : " + absolutePath);
                    db.close();
                });  
            });
        });
    });  
});

console.log("Number of XML inserted: " + counter);
```

=============================================================

Above code works Perfectly it reads all the files that are present in Data folder
i want to limit this
i.e Suppose i have 10 files in Data folder but want to read only first 5 files and after reading the first 5 files i want it to move in another folder say it "Done Reading"

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will do that what you want to do 
Use the index in forEach method it will provide you the file position from the array 
 based on the do one if condition you can perform task

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const log = console.log;
const path = require("path");
const folderPath = 'Data';
const folder = folderPath;

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");

    fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach((file, index) => {

        if (index == 3) { //replace value 3 as per ur condition 

          //also u can pass the value dynamically here

          const extname = path.extname(file);
          const filename = path.basename(file, extname);
          const absolutePath = path.resolve(folder, file);

          const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
            mergeAttrs: true,
            explicitArray: false
          });

          fs.readFile(absolutePath, (err, data) => {

            parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {

              dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(result, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("XML Uploaded Succesfully : " + absolutePath);
                db.close();
              });
            });
          });
        });
    });

}
else {

  // do for remaining files here which can read from other directory or whatever u want
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation and dont just post code. Also, to connect for each file to the database and close the connection is slow and can be avoided. Just open the connection and then do everything else. A lot of people do that wrong because of various Tutorials...

Comment: /// i HAVE USED .slice here  this works  fs.readdirSync(folder).slice(0,3).forEach((file,index) =>

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ex = require('fs-extra');

const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const log = console.log;
const path = require( "path" );
const folderPath = 'Data';
const folder = folderPath;
let counter = 0;

 fs.readdirSync(folder).slice(0,3).forEach((file,index) => {
     
    const extname = path.extname(file);
    const filename = path.basename(file, extname);
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(folder, file);
    const parser = new xml2js.Parser({
        mergeAttrs: true,
        explicitArray: false
    });
    
counter++;

fs.readFile(absolutePath, (err, data) => {
        parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                 if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("mydb");
                 dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(result, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
const dest = "readingDone/" + filename + extname;
 ex.move(absolutePath, dest, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('File successfully moved!!');
}); 
//console.log(extname);
console.log("XML Uploaded Succesfully : " + absolutePath);



                    db.close();
                });  
            });
        });
    });  
    
});

console.log("Number of XML inserted: " + counter);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.